# no rendered data from endpoint reactjs

Tags: reactjs, endpoint

I am building a project using Reactjs and ready endpoints to render the data from it.

I have been following [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3_f5ssj-pm8)

it was working fine until I got to render the data to the browser not only in the console

what am I doing wrong?

```
import {React, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


function App() {
   const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
   const [posts, setPosts] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  const getData = () => {
    const ENDPOINT= "https://snetmyapp.herokuapp.com/case1";
    axios (ENDPOINT)
    .then((response: any) => {
      setIsLoading(false);
      console.log("RES",response.data);
if (response.data.posts) {
     setPosts(response.data.posts)
    }
    else
    console.log("No posts");
    });
  };
    const data = isLoading ? (
       <p>Loading...</p>
       ) : (
          <div><pre>{JSON.stringify(posts, null, 2)}</pre></div>
          );
    return (
    <div>{data}</div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are no `posts` in returned data
`offerList` is returned instead.
[Check out this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-river-70dxl7?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: i have another question, now when i want to render specific data from the endpoint shall i refer to the data as 
 const dataRenderer= data.map((data => {
    return <div>{data.FirmName}</div>
  }))

Comment: @HazalKaya Well, that's one of the ways to do it. Or you can extract it in the `return` without creating a separate variable. If that's something complex you can even extract it to a separate component.

Comment: so can i just render it in the return direclty?